# JConsole isn't recognized as a command

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole

I'm trying to familiarize myself with JMX and I've been using the oracle tutorials to help me get up to speed. According to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/overview/javavm.html) link, I should run a Java application and then run *jconsole*.

However even though I have JDK 1.6.0_30 installed, jconsole is not a recognized command. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have the bin of the JDK on the path, or the JRE's bin? If it's the latter, it won't work.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that two seconds after I posted the question :-/ Feel like a fool. Thanks for your help

Comment: Nah, no foolishness, I've actually run into that problem quite often, which is why I thought of it so quickly. Glad it worked out.

Comment: I'm surprised that the Server JRE doesn't ship with it.